# How to define atlas on the set of triangles

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M:=\{ \bigtriangleup ABC| A=(0,0),B,C \in \mathbb{R}^{2}, \angle BAC=\dfrac{\pi}{3} \}$. I need to define smooth atlas on $M$. Could you please give me any hints how to define charts? (I've spent much time and have no ideas)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many dimensions will this manifold have?

Comment: @Berci I think, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: Well, $A$ is fixed in the origin, and what if we considered only the set of *line segments* $AB$ with arbitrary $B$? That would be just isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ as $A$ is fixed and $B$ can be whatever. Here the same, moreover we have a $C$ and the distance $AC$ is also arbitrary. So, this manifold will be 3 dimensional.

Comment: Which topology do you give to $M$? Do you regard it as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb R^4$?

Comment: @Berci:  I think it's $2$-dim, owing to the angle parameter.  Basically, you get to pick $B$ wherever, but then $C$ must lie on one of the two lines making an angle of $\pi/3$ with $AB$.  (So, I think there are two components).

Comment: One possible trick for proving it is a  smooth manifold: I think $f:\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=2\langle x,y\rangle -\|x\|\|y\|$ is smooth and  probably $0$ is a regular value and $f^{-1}(0)$ should be a smooth manifold.  Is this correct?